# Atualizar campo after insert

Tags: mysql, sql-update, trigger

Estou tentando criar uma trigger para atualizar um valor depois de inserir, ou antes se funcionasse.

Tenho a seguinte tabela: teste

Lembrando que o tipo do campo date é `timestamp` e o valor padrão é `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
id   |   date                   |   dado    |   dado2 
1    |   2018-10-22 14:43:32    |  Dado 1   |
2    |   2018-10-22 14:44:40    |  Dado 2   |
3    |   2018-10-22 14:44:41    |  Dado 3   |
4    |   2018-10-22 14:45:41    |  Dado 4   |
```

Se eu fizer a trigger usando `before insert`, ao usar o campo `new.date` o valor vem nulo.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `teste_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `teste` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  insert into debug_table (condicao, condicao2) VALUES (new.date, new.id);
END
```

Essa tabela debug_table foi que eu criei para saber se o valor está vindo, ele insere, mas com dado nulo

Mas se eu usar `after insert`, o campo vem preenchido. Só que eu gostaria de atualizar o campo `dado 2`.

Então já que o valor funciona com o `after insert`, eu gostaria de dar um update na mesma tabela com essa trigger no campo `dado 2`

Mas parece que não funciona o update

Comment: Não entendi bem, você insere na tabela e quer o que depois?